# Where should I initialize session library in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

*First off, I've checked if there was a similar question and there appears not to be. Please let me know if I'm re-asking an already answered question. Thanks.*

I'm new to codeIgniter and I do not know where to initialize the session library `$this->load->library('session');` .

Should I make a controler specifically for the session like in [this](http://runnable.com/UhIVTnEfFJEMAAB5/how-to-use-session-in-codeigniter) example? or should I put it in one of my already existing *controlers*?

Thus far my two main controlers are called **pages** and **user**. Here is part of the code for each.

**User:**

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

//login / inscription handler
class User extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){  
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('layout');
        //$this->load->library('session'); This is where I would logically load the library
        $this->layout->set_title('User');
    }
    public function add(){
            $this->load->model('/user/add');
            $this->add->user();
            $this->layout->add_includes('css', 'assets/css/success.css');
            $this->layout->view('pages/success');
    }
    public function connexion(){
            $this->load->model('/user/connexion');
            $user = $this->connexion->find();
            $newdata = array(

            );


            $this->layout->view('pages/logged');
    }
}



?>
```

**Pages:**

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        // load the library
        $this->load->library('layout');
        //$this->load->library('session') Or should I put it here?
        $this->layout->set_title('Pages');

    }

    public function index() {

        $this->layout->set_title('Welcome' . $this->layout->title_separator . 'Pages');
        $this->layout->add_includes('css', 'assets/css/home.css');
        $this->layout->view('pages/home');

    }
    public function contact()
    {
        $this->layout->add_includes('css', 'assets/css/contact.css');
        $this->layout->view('pages/contact');
    }
    public function nouveautes()
    {
        $this->layout->add_includes('css', 'assets/css/news.css');
        $this->layout->view('pages/news');
    }
    public function connexion()
    {
        $this->layout->view('pages/sign_in');
    }
    public function bureau()
    {
        $this->layout->add_includes('css', 'assets/css/board.css');
        $this->layout->view('pages/board');
    }
    public function membres()
    {
        $this->layout->add_includes('css', 'assets/css/members.css');
        $this->layout->view('pages/members');
    }
}
```

So, breaking it down. **Pages** controler pretty much loads all the main pages. **User** controler checks if the user is trying to sign up or sign in and will load a page saying "congratulations you are now logged in" (or not).

Notice in __consruct() of each controler a commented area of where I think I should load the library.

**Where should I initialize it? What's the most used method? Why?**

**Additional Information:**

What do I want to do with my session information? I would like whenever a user accesses my website (logged in or not) that a session is created. When the user logs in then I update the session with extra information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want a session to be created if the user is logged in, or not then why not use the autoloader (./application/config/autoload.php)?

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

This will allow you to access the session throughout your application.

Comment: Well that answered my question. Didn't even know that existed. So I add that and no matter who accesses my website will automaically have a session created? Thanks!

Comment: You should read through the user guide. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/autoloader.html